# Magento not showing the right version in footer

Tags: php

My magento installation is showing ver. 1.7.0.2 in the footer, but /downloader is showing:
Mage_All_Latest 1.8.0.0 (stable)

I have cleared var/cache, var/session and var/tmp but it's still showing 1.7.0.2.
How can I confirm which one of them that is showing the wrong version and how do I solve it if it isn't upgraded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version information in the footer is pulled from `app/Mage.php` in the code block below. It sounds like your system has done the usual Magento Connect partial upgrade because it has not overwritten app/Mage.php.

```
/**
 * Gets the current Magento version string
 * @link http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/new-community-edition-release-process/
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function getVersion()
{
    $i = self::getVersionInfo();
    return trim("{$i['major']}.{$i['minor']}.{$i['revision']}" . ($i['patch'] != '' ? ".{$i['patch']}" : "")
                    . "-{$i['stability']}{$i['number']}", '.-');
}

/**
 * Gets the detailed Magento version information
 * @link http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/new-community-edition-release-process/
 *
 * @return array
 */
public static function getVersionInfo()
{
    return array(
        'major'     => '1',
        'minor'     => '8',
        'revision'  => '0',
        'patch'     => '0',
        'stability' => '',
        'number'    => '',
    );
}
```

This usually is taken care of with a command line install using:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

As in all things Magento, you should be doing this first on a test server, and on a live production server, only after tarballing your Magento environment and doing a Magento database dump.

Comment: Worked perfectly, just had to fix some permissions afterwards.
Thank you! Too bad I don't have over 15 reputation here so I could give you an upvote.