# UPgrading magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

My magento installation is showing ver. 1.8.1.0 in the footer, but `/downloader` is showing: `Mage_All_Latest 1.9.3.1 (stable)`

I have cleared `var/cache`, `var/session` and `var/tmp` but it's still showing 1.8.1.0. How can I confirm which one of them that is showing the wrong version and how do I solve it if it isn't upgraded?

i am not tech savy so can you explain very simply what to do

apparently i have to run a command but dont know where and how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/magento-not-showing-the-right-version-in-footer